# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException on service call

Tags: java, web-services, illegalargumentexception

I'm so stuck with a problem and I haven't yet managed to find the real cause of the error.  I get `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The MessageContext does not have an associated SOAPFault` error while I try to call a web service method from client side. Unfortunately, there are very few information related the source and the solution of the problem on the net. In one of the forum, I've seen a post indicating that "this happens at the client side when a JSON response is a fault".

Below is the stack trace, any help is appreciated.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The MessageContext does not have an associated SOAPFault.
            at org.apache.axis2.util.Utils.getInboundFaultFromMessageContext(Utils.java:556)
            at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.handleResponse(OutInAxisOperation.java:375)
            at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:421)
            at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:229)
            at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:165)
            at tr.com.innova.ws.client.uavt.UavtServiceStub.degisiklikSorgula(UavtServiceStub.java:1089)
            at tr.com.innova.schedule.SenkronizasyonJobV2.execute(SenkronizasyonJobV2.java:199)
            at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:203)
            at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:531)
```

Comment: Did you check what are you returning on error? is it a valid xml document?

Comment: Please show us what is returned by the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, the client from which we were trying to request services from server was getting blocked by the server probably causing some changes in the message context. Once we configured the server to allow requests from our client machine it worked fine without any exception.